# Deleting Directory Contents & SubDirectory Contents

Tags: php, directory, delete-file

I've set up some PHP to delete a directory, it's contents, and any subdirectory and its contents... I'm new to PHP so I'm most definitely doing something WRONG or am doing something in the most inefficient way.

Looking for some references or suggestion on how to do this better...

By the way, this code works fine. Using PHP 5.3.8.

```
chmod($main_dir, 0755);
if ($handle = opendir($main_dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { 
        $absolute_path = $main_dir.'/'.$entry;
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {      
            chmod($absolute_path, 0755);
            unlink($absolute_path);

            //check if any folders exist, then delete files within
            if (file_exists($absolute_path) && is_dir($absolute_path)) {
                if ($child_handle = opendir($absolute_path)) {
                    while (false !== ($child_entry = readdir($child_handle))) {             
                    $child_absolute_path = $absolute_path.'/'.$child_entry;
                        if ($child_entry != "." && $child_entry != "..") {              
                            chmod($child_absolute_path, 0755);
                            unlink($child_absolute_path);
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($child_handle);
                }
            }
            rmdir($absolute_path);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
rmdir($main_dir);
```

Any thoughts? Much appreciated!
Im using PHP 5.3.8

Comment: This might be more appropriate on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: @shakabra      Thanks, gonna check it out now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to list all files and folders then delete them. Please Note that you have to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST` so that the files are deleted before the folder.

```
$dir = __DIR__ . "/test";
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ( $ri as $file ) {
    $file->isDir() ?  rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: WOW, so much simpler... Thanks! Been doing some reading on php.net, wish I knew about RecursiveDirectoryIterator ages ago.

Comment: @Terry learning is a continues thing ... Am glad i was able to help