# delete all the folders inside a parent folder

Tags: php, unlink, rmdir

How to delete all the folders inside a parent folder with PHP?

I have tried this, but it isn't working:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate `isnt working`?

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal `it is not working`

Comment: @vikram well that's helpful. -1 then.

Comment: it worked for me - do you get an exception? an error message? are you sure you're sending the right directory and you are currently located in the parent directory?

Comment: yep i am sending the right directory :( @Oded, NO, no error, nothing it is not doing anything !!! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Deleting Directory Contents & SubDirectory Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966227/php-deleting-directory-contents-subdirectory-contents)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
function del($dir) 
{ 
  foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) 
  { 
    if(is_dir($file))
        del($file); 
  } 
  rmdir($dir); 
}
```

It will also delete nested folders