# Reclusive Directory Remove not working?

Tags: php, directory, scandir, rmdir

I am trying to remove a directory and all of its contents with this script...

```
<?php
$app = $_POST['app'];

if (isset($_POST['app'])) {
    $dir = "../apps/" . $app . "/";

function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        rmdir($dir);
    }
}
}
?>
```

The $post is working fine and the script is not returning any errors but its just not deleting the directory. Could it have something to do with folder permissions? Do I need to activate any PHP extensions?

--EDIT--
The linked duplicate does not do what I want and I don't know how to change the code for it. I am deleting a directory on the client side so I can't use `__DIR__` as that keeps the path like this /test/app and I need them to be like this \test\app also the code does not remove the folder but it does remove all of the contents. I believe that is to do with the `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` line. I need the code to remove the folder as well because when or if the user installs the app again it wont work due to the duplicate folder.

Working code:

```
<?php
$app = $_POST['app'];

if (isset($_POST['app'])) {
$dir ="../apps/" . $app;

$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ( $ri as $file ) {
    $file->isDir() ?  rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
}
rmdir($dir);
}
?>
```

Comment: you really want to use the Accepted Answer in the linked dupe. It's much easier to use. Apart from that, you want to make sure the path is indeed below the '../apps/' folder. Right now a malicious user could use a Directory Traversal Attack and pass in '..' as the path which would result in '../apps/../' and I doubt you want that to happen.

Comment: Hi @Gordon thanks for the reply. could you please explain what `__DIR__` means or does before the directory path? and i have just used that code and my directory still isn't being deleted

Comment: I dont believe my question is a duplicate @Gordon could you please look at my updated question

Comment: I am reopening it although I am not sure I should. Can you clarify what you mean with you are deleting a directory on the client side? PHP runs at the server side. It doesn't have access to the client side. Also the direction of the slashes shouldn't matter as PHP will internally use the correct format for your platform. Also, you say it does delete the content but is just not deleting the top folder. That would be simple to solve by just rmdir'ing the path after the iterator is done deleting all the contents.

Comment: well when i used `__DIR__` i got an error and it was wrong in two ways. First it did not take into account the .. to go up a layer so the path started where the php file was and second the path from where it started had slashes the wrong way to the rest of the path. I  assumed that the iterator was supposed to 'rmdir' the directory at the end. I have added that line in at the end of the iterator and it is all working now. Thanks for all your help! i will put the complete code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966227/php-deleting-directory-contents-subdirectory-contents) @Gordon sent me to, helped get me the answer.

This is my new working code.

```
<?php
$app = $_POST['app'];

if (isset($_POST['app'])) {
$dir ="../apps/" . $app;

$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ( $ri as $file ) {
    $file->isDir() ?  rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
}
rmdir($dir);
}
?>
```